# Android onesignal push notifications do not appear after device reboot

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

**Problem**
In my webview app, I use onesignal to send user push notifications from my server. The device receives notifications not only when the app is running but also when it is completely closed. However, if I switch off and then switch on my phone, I do not get the notifications. And only after launching the app, I obtain those messages.

**Idea**
My idea was to launch my app on boot and immediately close it, so the user does not even notice it. However, I do not think it is a very good solution.

How do the developers usually solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please tell me what device(s) model you are using?

Comment: Google pixel 3 emulator

Comment: does this problem happen on real devices?

Comment: I tried it on real three devices as well: OnePlus 7 Pro, Huaweii p10+ and Samsung Note (very old). I didn't receive the notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you must wait at least 24 hr after reboot to make sure that the notifications are delivered or not ([per documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-notifications-work#section-notifications-when-app-is-closed))

[image: sample]

To make this waiting period shorter you should set the notification Priority to `high priority 10`

> High Priority: These notifications are delivered immediately, though fall subject to the standby bucket policy on the device.
>
> Set a high priority 10 if you need it to go through any doze mode /
> other power saving modes. But only use priority 10 when you really
> need to as there is a daily limit where it might fallback to normal
> priority.

Comment: Could you please hint where I should set this priority?